# GPGAppstateModel does not exist in new gpg.framework 4.1.1

Tags: ios, google-play-games

After update to gpg.framework ver 4.1.1, I found out that GPGAppstateModel no longer exist, so some commands in my iOS game return an error.
Example of the code I used to load token in my game:

```
GPGAppStateModel *model = [GPGManager sharedInstance].applicationModel.appState;
    NSNumber *totalTokensKey = [NSNumber numberWithInt:CloudSaveKey_TotalTokens];

    [model loadForKey:totalTokensKey completionHandler:^(GPGAppStateLoadStatus status, NSError *error) {
        if (status == GPGAppStateLoadStatusNotFound) {
            // Data for this key does not exist. This must be the first time our user
            // played this game
            NSLog(@"Total tokens does not exist");

        } else {}
}
```

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Anyone have any solution? :(

Comment: AppState has been deprecated and replaced with SavedGames API.  Is this a released game, or one in development?

Comment: It's still in development, I'll try SavedGames API.

Comment: @Clayton Wilkinson:  After used SavedGames API, sometimes I met ConflictId with this [GPGSnapshotMetadata openWithFileName:...], How can I solve it?